# How can i make buttons the same width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have here 2 buttons and i want them to have the same width

here is a image
[image]

and here is the code:

```
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">My Linkies</h5>
    <p class="card-text">total LINK</p>
    <p class="card-text">total linki</p>
    <p class="card-text">usd</p>
    <a class="card-link text-left">Reward</a>
   <a class="card-link" id="myDividends">LINK</a><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="button"> Reinvest</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="button"> withdraw</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to change css

```
.btn {
  padding: 10;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: tried setting a width? width: 50%?

Comment: @AugustoM with 50% width they get the same size but they are below each other and not next to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are wrapping because you have padding on the button. Figure out what your padding is or set it to 0 in your css file. in this example i used 5px as my padding. Then set the utilized calc to set the width to 50% sans the 10px (5 right, 5 left) of padding

```css
.btn {
  padding: 5px;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">My Linkies</h5>
    <p class="card-text">total LINK</p>
    <p class="card-text">total linki</p>
    <p class="card-text">usd</p>
    <a class="card-link text-left">Reward</a>
   <a class="card-link" id="myDividends">LINK</a><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="button"> Reinvest</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="button"> withdraw</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to have is same width for both the buttons, you can simply achieve that by specifying a width for the buttons.

```
<style>
.card-body button{
    width:100px;
    }

</style>
```

```css
 .card-body button{
        width:100px;

        }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">My Linkies</h5>
        <p class="card-text">total LINK</p>
        <p class="card-text">total linki</p>
        <p class="card-text">usd</p>
        <a class="card-link text-left">Reward</a>
        <a class="card-link" id="myDividends">LINK</a><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="button"> Reinvest</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="button"> withdraw</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Note: If you have dynamic text to the button, I recommend mentioning a `max-width` so that you won't break the container and mess up the appearance. Hope that helpsssss

Answer (score 0):

If there's a specific width you want, you could add a class (or just use btn as in your sample CSS) to set the width. However, if you want to dynamically size them all to match the width of the largest button (in this case, make Buy match the width of Approve), then you'd need to add some Javascript to loop through all of the buttons, find the largest width, and then set them all to that width.

*Edit: added sample Javascript*

Assuming you have jquery available (likely, given that you're using bootstrap), that could look something like this:

```js
// Check the maximum width of all buttons in the card-body (could use an ID if you add one to your HTML)
var maxWidth = 0;
$('.card-body .btn').each(function(index, element) {
    var curWidth = $(element).width();
    if (maxWidth < curWidth ) {
        maxWidth = curWidth;
    }
});

// Set all buttons to the max width
$('.card-body .btn').width(maxWidth);
```

Comment: you kidding me dude- i need all that jquery just to makke buttons the same width?

Comment: @redbulll That depends exactly what you're after, and how dynamic you want it to be. If you use a fixed width or a percentage, then a user with the font size set very high (for accessibility reasons, for instance) would end up with the text in the button getting cut off or wrapping. That's the beauty of dynamic sizing. The problem is, if you let the buttons get sized dynamically, then they'll each be a different size. Using Javascript can give you the best of both worlds. If a fixed width is good enough for your use case, then you can avoid the JS altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a width for both buttons, like 150px, or you could give them both a width in %.

Fixed width:

```css
.card-body{
text-align:center;
}
.card-body .btn{
width:150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">My Linkies</h5>
    <p class="card-text">total LINK</p>
    <p class="card-text">total linki</p>
    <p class="card-text">usd</p>
    <a class="card-link text-left">Reward</a>
   <a class="card-link" id="myDividends">LINK</a><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="button"> Reinvest</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="button"> withdraw</button>
  </div>
```

Width in %. You'll need a wrapper for this.

```css
.card-body{
text-align:center;
}
.card-body .btn-wrap{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

.card-body{
  width:100%;
}

.card-body .btn{
  width:calc(50% - 10px);
}

.btn{
padding:10
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">My Linkies</h5>
    <p class="card-text">total LINK</p>
    <p class="card-text">total linki</p>
    <p class="card-text">usd</p>
    <a class="card-link text-left">Reward</a>
  <div class="btn-wrap">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="button"> Reinvest</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="button"> withdraw</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding
By the way, for padding to work it needs a unit like "px" or "%" or other. It's also not the most straightforward way to get button the same width.